# why does coroutine release the thread when suspended?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the documentation on coroutines, it is written that "at the points of suspension (for example, a request to the network), coroutine suspends its execution and releases the thread while waiting for a response"

My question is - why is the stream released when requested to the network? Waiting for a response is also an operation that should be expected on the thread. Why do I need to release the thread?

Answer (score 1):

The point is, you don’t have to block the current thread while waiting for the suspend function to do whatever time-consuming task it might be doing using other thread(s). Then when it’s done, it can return the result back on the original thread, that is, if the suspend function was called while in the context of a single-threaded dispatcher.

Here's a common sort of scenario. The UI views can only be worked with on the main thread, but we cannot block the main thread to wait for something because that freezes the entire UI, making it unresponsive. This would be a horrible experience for the user because they cannot interact with the device at all and the screen is frozen while waiting. So we use a suspending function for the time-consuming actions that must not block the main thread.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    // The lifecycle scope uses the single-threaded Dispatchers.Main.

    showProgressIndicator() // A regular, non-blocking function that works with the UI

    val result = getSomethingFromTheNetwork() // A suspend function call. The main thread 
                                              // is now released so we aren't blocking 
                                              // it while we wait for the time-consuming
                                              // network fetch. The main thread will
                                              // continue to be used by other code
                                              // and be free to show animation and
                                              // accept user input.

    // The suspend function returns a value, and we have assigned it to the result 
    // variable above after resuming on the main thread again.

    hideProgressIndicator() // We can safely work with UI on the main thread.
    updateUI(result)
}
```

Under the hood, that `getSomethingFromTheNetwork()` function must appropriately delegate its time-consuming work to threads that are acceptable to block. If it just naively does blocking work without appropriately suspending, then it is breaking convention, and will still block the calling thread. That would defeat the purpose of suspend functions.

Comment: and what is the point of suspending the coroutine, freeing the thread and delegating receiving a response from the server to another thread? this is if the executions already occur on the IO thread

Comment: you can just run another coroutine in another thread (to which the waiting response from the server was delegated), isn't it? @Tenfour04

Comment: If you’re already on a thread dedicated to IO, then you might still consider if if you had a whole bunch of concurrent IO going on and don’t want one series of sequential tasks to hog a thread for a long time and prevent other shorter jobs from finishing. I don’t understand your second comment.

Comment: Beyond working with UI, work is often more complicated than purely a sequence of IO operations. You might want to switch to doing something heavy on the CPU (and therefore switch to a thread pool that takes that into account for better consideration of the number of available CPU cores), or you may simply want to wait a certain amount of time for something without blocking *any* threads so the threads can be working on other tasks, or you might want to wait for a shared resource to become available without blocking.

Comment: The point is to use threads (which are expensive to create and tear down) more efficiently.  Suspending like that is the entire point of coroutines.  Without that suspension, the entire feature would be pointless-  you'd just use a thread instead.  With suspension a single thread can swap between multiple coroutines as each has processing to do, meaning you avoid those heavy startup times for each asynchronous request.

Comment: @Tebfour04, in your example, won't `getSomethingFromTheNetwork` won't switch to another thread automatically, will it?? For him, you clearly need to specify a context change via `withContext`?

Comment: so `getSomethingFromTheNetwork` will be called in the `main` thread and will block it

Comment: @seniorsalaga Assuming `getSomethingFromTheNetwork()` is a suspend function, it should handle the switching itself, not its caller. As a caller of a function, I should not be required to know its internals, what does it do and if it needs switching or not and to which threads. This is its implementations details.

Comment: @broot. well, there should be an understanding of the work)

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer explains that. If a suspend function does something blocking, it should do it inside an internal `withContext` block. Or if it interacts with asynchronous code from outside the coroutines world, it should wait for the result by using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. By convention, we should never have to worry about selecting a context *outside* a suspend function call. This follows the programming principle of encapsulation.